# XSL for-each with position to get dynamic column-number

Tags: xml, xslt

This is not working for me. I am trying to get the correct number of additional columns for my table depending upon the number of nodes in my XML. In this example, I have two "stuff" nodes, but my XML data can have between one and four, and thus my table can have between one and four additional columns. The first column will always be there.

Here's my XML:

```
<stuff>
    <thing>house</thing>
    <color>red</color>
</stuff>
<stuff>
    <thing>hat</thing>
    <color>brown</color>
</stuff>
```

Here's my XSL:

```
<fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
    <fo:table-column column-width="27%" column-number="1"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="stuff">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <fo:table-column column-width="73%" column-number="2"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=2">
            <fo:table-column column-width="36.5%" column-number="2"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="36.5%" column-number="3"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=3">
            <fo:table-column column-width="24%" column-number="2"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="24%" column-number="3"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="25%" column-number="4"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=4">
            <fo:table-column column-width="18.25%" column-number="2"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="18.25%" column-number="3"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="18.25%" column-number="4"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="18.25%" column-number="5"/>
        </xsl:if>                                   
    </xsl:for-each>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block>First Row</fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:for-each select="stuff">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="thing"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-row> 
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block>Second Row</fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:for-each select="stuff">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-row>         
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why my closing table tag `</fo:table>` is not showing up, but I did type it in.

Comment: To see the end tag you need to add 4 space characters before it. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want to do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent-of-stuff">
    <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
        <fo:table-column column-width="27%" column-number="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="count(stuff)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="stuff">
            <fo:table-column column-width="{73 div $n}%" column-number="{position() + 1}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- the rest of the table -->

  </fo:table>  
</xsl:template>
```

If the result of `column-width="24.3333333333333%"` for the 3-column scenario is not acceptable, then do:

```
<xsl:template match="parent-of-stuff">
    <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
        <fo:table-column column-width="27%" column-number="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="count(stuff)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="stuff">
            <fo:table-column column-number="{position() + 1}">
                <xsl:attribute name="column-width">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$n=3 and position()=3">25%</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$n=3">24%</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="73 div $n" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </fo:table-column>
        </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- the rest -->

  </fo:table>  
</xsl:template>
```